# Why am I able to compile kernel modules without "#include"ing the relevant header files?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Based on the common practices shouldn't I have to include `<linux/stat.h>` and `<linux/module_param.h>` in the following program?

```
#include<linux/module.h>

char str[7] = "hello";
int arr_size = 7;

module_param_string(str_param, str, 7, S_IRWXU);

int f1(void){

        return 0;
}

void f2(void){

}

module_init(f1);
module_exit(f2);


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");
```

But this compiles without any warning and module works without any problem. Is there a change in the header structure etc since version 2.6 (most of the books on drivers doesn't seem to have been updated since then.)?

For example [this](http://lwn.net/Articles/22197/) article by Jonathan Corbet explicitly says that we should include the module_param.h file for module parameters:

> Modules with parameters should now include `<linux/moduleparam.h>` explicitly.

Yet that doesn't seem to be needed at all. What am I missing?

Comment: It says _should_, not _must_. Look at the module.h header.

Comment: Thanks! I see module.h includes both moduleparam.h and stat.h and many other files. Wouldn't it create extra overhead for progrmas that might not need them though. I thought one of the advantages of having seperate headers for different kind of things was that we could include only what we needed..

Comment: That's precisely why it says _should_. They'll probably clean up that module header at some point.